# В setEnabled приложение останавливается

Tags: android

Это мой Java код:

```
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
JSONArray jarray= new JSONArray(EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity));
String pr = jarray.getJSONObject(0).getString("p");
int repon = Integer.parseInt(pr);
if(repon == 1){
Intent login = new Intent(this, joinorsign.class);
login.putExtra("name",pr);
startActivity(login);
}
if(repon == 3){
text3.setEnabled(true); /// ПОЧЕМУ ТУТ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ ОСТАНАВЛИВАЕТСЯ?
}
```

Если

```
if(repon == 3){
Intent login = new Intent(this, joinorsign.class);
login.putExtra("name",pr);
startActivity(login);
}
```

то приложение не останавливается.

Comment: Что значит останавливается? Виснет или бросает исключение? Можно поточнее? Stacktrace не мешало бы.

Answer (score 4):

Попробую себя в роли Ванги: обращение к UI элементу не из UI потока

Comment: Или text3 == null